# Is ARP table self-learning?

Tags: arp

I'm learning data communications and networking.

Here is my question about ARP's mechanism:

Suppose host A and B knows each other's IP address but don't know each other's MAC address. Then when A wants to send IP datagram to B, A needs to go through the ARP processes:

1. Broadcast the ARP request to the LAN (with B's IP address asking for B's MAC address).
2. Host B receives the request, and send ARP reply to A (by unicast).
3. Host A receives the reply.
4. Now A knows B's MAC address i.e., A's ARP table has B's entry.

BUT How about B's ARP table? Does it has A's entry?

If B receives A's IP datagram and want to send back some IP datagram to A, does B need to go through the above ARP processes to get A's MAC address?

Does ARP table has self-learning mechanism (like switch table), which can update its entry when receiving an ARP request ?

Thanks!